# Copy data between certain range in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new to VBA and stuck on one problem.
I want to copy data between certain values from selected file based on values in column A and paste them into file that is using this macro. There are a lot of files(that's why I need to select specific one) and data I need is not always in the same place, some files have the data I need in range (for example) A51:AQ143 while other have range A78:BB201 and those two text values are always the same in every file. As of now this macro copies only data from column A. By the way column A has blank values between this two text values, and unfortunately I can't amend file that I copy data from. Thanks in advance! :)

````
   Dim Fname As String
   Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
   Dim DestWbk As Workbook
   
   Set DestWbk = ThisWorkbook
   
   Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")
   If Fname = "False" Then Exit Sub
   Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)
   
   SrcWbk.Sheets("Template").Range(Range("A:BZ").Find("Source and Element Map"), Range("A:BZ").Find("Combinations")).Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Table").Range("A1")
   
   SrcWbk.Close False
   
End Sub```
````

Comment: `"Source and Element Map"` and `"Combinations"` are always in column A? your goal is to copy all the columns with data from the row containing `"Source and Element Map"` to the row containing `"Combinations"`?

Comment: Yes they are always in column A. For example if "Source and Element Map"" is A51 and "Combinations" is A209 i want to copy all data between A52 and BZ208.

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of workbooks to be processed? instead of manually opening each file, you could automate this in one code. Can you determine a row which will always in all workbooks in sheet "Template` contain data in its right-most cell which is in the last column of the data you need e.g.headers? If you want to write all data to worksheet `Table`, do you want to append the data i.e. write it starting from the next 'available' row (not overwriting from cell `A1` down)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, should copy the whole rows for all your data between the 2 words:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    
    Dim Fname As String: Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")
    If Fname = "False" Then Exit Sub
    Dim SrcWbk As Workbook: Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname, False, True)
    With SrcWbk.Sheets("Template")
        'find the first row to copy
        Dim FirstRow As Long: FirstRow = .Range("A:A").Find("Source and Element Map").Row
        'find the last row to copy
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = .Range("A:A").Find("Combinations").Row
        Dim RangeToCopy As Range
        Dim cell As Range
        'loop from the first row to the last
        For Each cell In .Range("A" & FirstRow, "A" & LastRow)
            'avoid empty rows (in column A)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
                'store all the eligible rows in one variable
                If RangeToCopy Is Nothing Then
                    Set RangeToCopy = cell
                Else
                    Set RangeToCopy = Union(RangeToCopy, cell)
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
    'paste the whole row for each cell stored in the Range Variable
    RangeToCopy.EntireRow.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table").Range("A1")
   SrcWbk.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: It works fine when changed:
  `'avoid empty rows (in column A)
            If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then`
To:
    `'avoid empty rows (in column A)
            If IsEmpty(cell) Then`

Since I want to copy data from this range when A is empty, other than that code works fine, thank you Damian! :)

Comment: My bad then! Thought you didn't want blank data. Glad I could help.